# $http.get success in AngularJs can't access factory which called it

Tags: angularjs

I've got a factory which looks a little bit like this:

```
app.factory('MyFactory',['$http',function($http){
    return {
        state: {
            collectionOfThings: {}
        },
        getThings: function() {
            $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
                this.state.collectionOfThings = data;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

All it provides is a method which gets a thing from a web service, and I want to store the answer in `state.collectionOfThings`. However, when the `$http` success method is called, `this` no longer refers to the factory and refers to `window`. I would have thought this was quite a straightforward thing to do, but I can't figure it out.

How do I populate the field in the factory with the results from the `$http.get`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
app.factory('MyFactory',['$http',function($http){
    var obj = {};
    obj.state = {
        collectionOfThings: {}
    };
    obj.getThings = function() {
        $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
            obj.state.collectionOfThings = data;
        });
    }
    return obj;
}]);
```